# Uncaught 500 error in WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api

I have WebApi2 project, that I publish to Azure.

It runs and I see my Views (Main view and API View with methods).

When I send request to back-end via postman , for example to this Link

> http://timetrackingbackend.azurewebsites.net/api/EndPauses

It needs to show me  all data (in my example it's one row in database)

Here is screen of my request

[image]

And code of controller method

```
 public class EndPausesController : ApiController
{
    private trackingappEntities db = new trackingappEntities();

    // GET: api/EndPauses
    public IQueryable<EndPause> GetEndPauses()
    {
        return db.EndPauses;
    }

    // GET: api/EndPauses/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(EndPause))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetEndPause(int id)
    {
        EndPause endPause = db.EndPauses.Find(id);
        if (endPause == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(endPause);
    }

    // PUT: api/EndPauses/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutEndPause(int id, EndPause endPause)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != endPause.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(endPause).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!EndPauseExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    // POST: api/EndPauses
    [ResponseType(typeof(EndPause))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostEndPause(EndPause endPause)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.EndPauses.Add(endPause);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = endPause.Id }, endPause);
    }

    // DELETE: api/EndPauses/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(EndPause))]
    public IHttpActionResult DeleteEndPause(int id)
    {
        EndPause endPause = db.EndPauses.Find(id);
        if (endPause == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        db.EndPauses.Remove(endPause);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok(endPause);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private bool EndPauseExists(int id)
    {
        return db.EndPauses.Count(e => e.Id == id) > 0;
    }
}
```

}

no one of  methods not work on prod.

With same request , but on localhost, all works great.

How I can understood where is problem?

I have no info instead of `status:500 internal server error`

Thank's for help.
**UPDATE**

Here is my route config

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

**UPDATE2**

I turn of custom errors in config file and now  get this error

```
{
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage": "The underlying provider failed on Open.",
"ExceptionType": "System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException",
"StackTrace": "   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<SaveChangesInternal>b__27()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()\r\n   at trackingappbackend.Controllers.EndPausesController.PostEndPause(EndPause endPause) in C:\\Users\\nemes\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\Projects\\trackingappbackend\\trackingappbackend\\Controllers\\EndPausesController.cs:line 85\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()",
"InnerException": {
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Cannot open database \"trackingappdb\" requested by the login. The login failed.\r\nLogin failed for user 'nemesises'.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<Open>b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.<Open>b__2()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()"
}
```

}

How I can fix it?

Comment: Have up updated the connection string from dev to production?

Comment: You have to check your webconfig file and connection string your database should be on production side

Comment: You mean connection string in Web.Release.config? If yes, I updated.@ChrisBint

Comment: and you have to check your routing file as well

Comment: I updated my question@LaxmanGite

Comment: It might be prudent to add a 'LogErrors' attribute on the controller methods and get this to send notifications to you. Without this, you are a little blind as to what the problem is.

Comment: I updated my question @ChrisBint

Comment: @SukhomlinEugene Something not right your either your connection string, or the DB configuration. Not much I can add, I would suggest reviewing accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error log is literally telling you what exactly is wrong:

"ExceptionMessage": "Cannot open database \"trackingappdb\" requested by the login. The login failed.\r\nLogin failed for user 'nemesises'.",

Go to your production config transform and inspect the connection string to make sure the username/password combo is appropriate and can connect to your prod DB.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the controller with action name.

### Example :-

http://timetrackingbackend.azurewebsites.net/api/EndPauses/GetEndPauses

Comment: Error was in database name